# How can I perform a bulk DNS query using perl on Unix/Linux?

Tags: perl, unix, dns

I have a list of systems for which I'm trying to get IP addresses.  I've successfully used the Net::DNS module for perl to perform an IP address query for a single hostname.  I have 1,000 systems, however, that I need ip addresses for.

Is there a way to get all of these ip addresses with a single query?

If not, is there a way to get the entire DNS entry list, say, for a single domain?  If I got that, then I could simply put that into a hash and reference the IP addresses that way.

Comment: Is there a reason you don't just loop over the hostnames?

Comment: Performance.  I just don't want to make 1,000 separate queries when doing 1 could suffice!

Comment: Have you proven that making 1,000 separate queries will adversely affect the performance of your program or the DNS server?  If not, then you are optimizing prematurely.  Most DNS servers can handle tens of thousands of queries per second, I would not expect there to be a problem with just querying it in a loop.

Comment: Some domains will allow you to AXFR their zone data, but I would advise strongly against exploring this. Just do a loop over your 1000 entries. Your local DNS server will cache results so most repeats won't travel very far.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No need for custom Perl. This can be done using the `-f` option to `dig` (part of the BIND tools):

```
$ dig -f /path/to/host-list.txt
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I was aware of the dig command but it seemed like an awful lot of parsing compared to the neat objects Net::DNS returns.  I'll consider this the accepted answer if I don't receive a "cleaner" answer though.

Comment: It can be made more quiet and succinct -- still requires some parsing, but do explore the options.

Comment: Actually, after playing with it, the +noall +answer options look like exactly what I'd be looking for, with a lot easier parsing.

Answer (score 3):

For a large domain dataset, this'll do it fast with no real need to parse the results; an IP will always be in `$results{$domain}[0][4]`. It's not a single query, but they'll be done concurrently (max of 10 queries in progress at any one time IIRC) so will be done quickly. Just make sure the DNS server operator doesn't have a problem with that many requests in a short period.

```
use AnyEvent::DNS;
use Data::Dumper;

my @domains = qw/google.com/;
my $resolver = AnyEvent::DNS->new( server => '8.8.4.4' );
my %results;

### Set up the condvar
my $done = AE::cv;
$done->begin( sub { shift->send } );

for my $domain (@domains) {
  $done->begin;
  $resolver->resolve($domain, 'a', sub {push @{$results{$domain}}, \@_; $done->end;});
}

### Decrement the cv counter to cancel out the send declaration
$done->end;

### Wait for the resolver to perform all resolutions
$done->recv;

print Dumper \%results;
```

Outputs:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'google.com' => [
                            [
                              'google.com',
                              'a',
                              'in',
                              300,
                              '74.125.225.52'
                            ],
                            [
                              'google.com',
                              'a',
                              'in',
                              300,
                              '74.125.225.50'
                            ],
                            [
                              'google.com',
                              'a',
                              'in',
                              300,
                              '74.125.225.49'
                            ],
                            [
                              'google.com',
                              'a',
                              'in',
                              300,
                              '74.125.225.48'
                            ],
                            [
                              'google.com',
                              'a',
                              'in',
                              300,
                              '74.125.225.51'
                            ]
                          ]
        };
```

Comment: Thanks for answer.  We might actually go with this solution, even if it isn't, technically, the answer to the question (there are still 1,000 queries being done).

Comment: Yeah, I'm guessing you were trying to consolidate them cause Net::DNS is sloooow. This is non-blocking, can fit alongside other event based programming, and generally should just work. You can't actually query multiple domain lookups in a single packet; it's just not the way the protocol works. Behind the scenes, something like dig is still going to be doing multiple lookups. C/f http://groups.google.com/group/comp.protocols.dns.bind/browse_thread/thread/b8e5b13649bb0158